# Cryptic error while exiting ipython

Tags: python, scrapy

When exiting ipython I got the following error:

```
In [3]: 
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? y

Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  File "/root/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 130, in start_reactor
  File "/root/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1192, in run
  File "/root/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1206, in mainLoop
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'msg'
```

I did a restart and it doesn't happen anymore. This was the ipython REPL within a `scrapy shell` command. Within the REPL there were no errors in the code I ran.

Comment: Also, can you recall what code have you executed in the shell (if matters)?

Comment: Do you get this same error when you type "quit()"?